# Dynamic height and webkit-transition

Tags: javascript, dojo, css, transition

I use CSS3 to animate my page, but I have a problem with a composant : the height of this one is calculated in Javascript (Dojo), and is applied with the function `dojo.style(mycomposant,calculatedHeight)`. I've set the following css property to this composant : "-webkit-tansition: height 5s linear", but because I applied the property by javascript, the transition is not used...

Has anybody a solution ?

Nicolas

Comment: Have your tried : webkitTransition instead of -webkit-tansition?

Comment: Actually ... I made a mistake : my solution worked ! But it seems that the ipad doesn't manage correctly transitions on height, width, left, etc. ... It's very jerky !!

Answer (score 1):

It should work. 
please use:  `-webkit-transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out;`